# How to access public property of parent function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces

I am trying to write some javascript functions for a web application.

Following the advice from here: [How do I declare a namespace in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/javascript-namespace-declaration)

I am trying to make the code unobtrusive by wrapping everything in named functions, however I am running into difficulty accessing properties in the parent function when inside a child anonymous function.

For example:

```
var title_picker = new function(){
    // This property should be public
    this.callback=function(){};


    var ok=function(){
        var title = $('input#title').val();
        callback(title) // <--- 
    }
...
```

When inside the "ok" function, what is the best way to reference the "callback" property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the code as written, no there isn't.

You can access variables from the scope of the parent, unless they are overwritten in the narrower scope.

`this` is always overwritten.

You can copy `this` to another variable that remains in scope though:

```
var title_picker = new function(){

    var self = this; // Copy this to a variable that stays in scope

    // This property should be public
    this.callback = function(){};


    var ok=function(){
        var title = $('input#title').val();
        self.callback(title) // self is still in scope
    }
...
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it will do the trick nicely. Out of interest why the aversion to the new keyword. My understanding is a big vague over what the new keyword does in general. In this case it seems to run the function and returns its "this" scope, which is what I want in this case. (To be able to for example trigger title_picker.show() from elsewhere in my code).

Comment: @Chris — You're using a function expression. You use `new` when you call a function you defined earlier that you are going to use like a class … and argh. No, I think you need `this` there. I've just never seen anyone use a function *expression* like that.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this:

```
var title_picker = new function(){
    // This property should be public
    this.callback=function(){};
    var that = this;


    var ok=function(){
        var title = $('input#title').val();
        that.callback(title) // <--- 
    }
...
```

Though there are many frameworks that do this kind of thing for you (yui, dojo, prototype...)